# Python nested for loops - inner loop iterator type change

Tags: python, loops, types, nested, iterator

In this function, `exs` is assumed to be a list of lists of floats. It represents the list of all my training examples, each of which is a list (length `num_vars`) of floats, representing perceptron input. `target` is assumed to be a list (length `num_vars`) of floats, representing the target function's coefficients.

```
def gradDesc(exs, target, num_vars, n=0.5, its=256):
    import random
    weights = []
    # Create and initialize delWeights to 0. Make its size num_vars.
    delWeights = [0.0]*num_vars


    # Initializes the weights to a real number in [-1,1]. Also makes weights
    # contain num_vars entries.
    for i in range(num_vars):
        weights.append(random.uniform(-1,1))

    # To make the printouts look nicer
    print("Iteration\tError")
    print("---------\t-----")

    for i in range(its):

        # Reset delWeights to 0
        for j in range(num_vars):
            delWeights[j] = 0

        for e in exs:

            # Plug e into the current hypothesis and get the output.
            output = test_hypo(weights, e, num_vars)

            print("delWeights: ", delWeights)
            for dw in delWeights:
                print("type(dw): ", type(dw))
                delWeights[dw] = delWeights[dw] + n*(test_hypo(target, e, num_vars) - output)*e[dw]

        for w in weights:
            weights[w] = weights[w] + delWeights[dw]

        # Print out the error every tenth iteration
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(i + "\t" + train_err(exs, target, weights, num_vars))

    # Print out the final hypothesis
    print(i + "\t" + train_err(exs, target, weights, num_vars))

    return weights
```

The problem is, when I try to run this given the (finite) test input

```
trainers = 
[[1, 2.7902232015508766, -4.624194135789617], 
[1, -7.964359679418456, 2.1940274082288624], 
[1, 8.445941538761794, -8.86567924774781], 
... other sub-lists following this same format ...]
```

and

```
target = [-2, 1, 2]
```

I get this odd output:

```
gradDesc(trainers, target, num_vars)
Iteration       Error
---------       -----
delWeights:  [0, 0, 0]
type(dw):  <class 'int'>
type(dw):  <class 'int'>
type(dw):  <class 'int'>
delWeights:  [0.0, 0, 0]
type(dw):  <class 'float'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-97298b385113>", line 1, in <module>
    gradDesc(trainers, target, num_vars)

  File "C:/Users/Me/.spyder-py3/Machine Learning/gradDesc.py", line 107, in gradDesc
    delWeights[dw] = delWeights[dw] + n*(test_hypo(target, e, num_vars) - output)*e[dw]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

So my question is: why is the type of `dw` changing from an int to a float on the second iteration through the `for e in exs` loop?

Comment: Why are you using the `dw` variable outside the `for dw in delweights:` loop?

Comment: Why do you first initialize `delWeights` to a list of `0.0`, then replace it with `0` inside the `for i in range(its):` loop? Why not `delWeights = [0]*num_vars`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delWeights[dw] = delWeights[dw] + n*(test_hypo(target, e, num_vars) - output)*e[dw]
```

sets `delWeights[dw]` to a float, because `e[dw]` is a float. So the next time you do the `for dw in delWeights:` loop, `dw` is a float.

It doesn't make sense to use the elements of `delWeights` as indexes. If you want to iterate over a list and also get the indexes, you should use `enumerate()`

```
for i, dw in enumerate(delWeights):
    delWeights[i] = dw + n*(test_hypo(target, e, num_vars) - output)*e[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to loop through the indexes of `delWeight` using `for i in range(len(delWeights))` instead of `for dw in delWeights`?

`for dw in delWeights` loops through all the values in `delWeights`, so the first iteration of your loop probably assigns a float to one of the `delWeights` indices in `delWeights[dw] + n*(test_hypo(target, e, num_vars) - output)*e[dw]`.